# How to interpret this condition on the empty set?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How should we interpret:

$\forall k\in \emptyset$ proposition on k,

and

$\exists k \in \emptyset$ proposition on k.

I would say the first is always true, for all k in empty set, I tend to read it as If there's a k in empty set, then something. 
The second I would read as there exists a k in empty set in which we have the proposition as true.

This is just my intuition. I'm looking for a formal reasoning (not too much though) of why this is so, or not...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first is always true, the second is always false. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Let $\varphi$ denote a property and $X$ be a set. Then, formally,  the  statement $\forall x\in X (\varphi(x))$ is a shortcut for $\forall x(x\in X \to \varphi(x))$, which reads as 'every element of $X$ has the property $\varphi$'. Similarly for the existential quantifier: $\exists x\in X (\varphi(x))$ is a shortcut for $\exists x(x\in X$ and $\varphi(x))$. This is usually called a *bounded quantification*.

Now it is easy to determine the truth of these statements assuming $X=\emptyset$ simply applying knowledge from (classical) propositional logic. E.g. the first formula is always true because the premise of the implication is always false (one of the paradoxes of material implication).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, specially on the formalisation of the two statements. ;)